# How to align items in ItemsControl in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I have a problem with locating item into canvas dynamically and would really appreciate any help for my question.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Flags}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Label Content="{Binding Count}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.182,-0.732" />
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" Margin="11,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Source="{Binding Path}" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Color}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have a

```
ObservableCollection<Flag> Flags = new ...
```

and in this collection I have 4 flags and I want to located each in the one of the corner of my canvas

The first flag in the left top of canvas, the second in right top
third in left bottom and the forth in right bottom corner

So how can I set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to my grid.
Something like this

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalAlignment}" ...
```

Comment: *Something like this `<Grid HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalAlignment}" >`* means that there's a HorizontalAlignment property in class Flag.

Comment: @Clemens yes you right. Also I try canvas instead of grid but the result is the same.